# Configure indentation in LESS CSS

Tags: configuration, indentation, less

I recently started using LESS(http://lesscss.org/) for writing my CSS. It is great and I love it but I couldn't find how to configure the indentation of the output CSS file. By default it is 2 spaces, but I am used to using 4 spaces(and I am also required since I pass the CSS file to other people).

Must be something very simple, but there's very little documentation and I couldn't find my way around the sourcecode of LESS...

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that's a configurable option.. and the intent is to NOT to worry about your .css files after you've done everything in LESS.

But if you must.. I think your option is to do that in your text-editor, or even better, have others worry about this ;)